# Is Agent J son of the Cop who died at the end

Tags: plot-explanation, men-in-black-3

I watched [Men In Black 3 (2012)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_in_Black_3). Here as Griffin (the man who could see future) told that someone should have to die, if it's not Agent K, then it would be someone else.

Exactly according to it, a cop was killed by Boris the Animal was intentially going to kill Agent K. Then the cop's kid came to Agent K asking for his father. I dont exactly remember the child's name, but it was something starting with J (might be Jonathan). Then Agent J, who was their from future thought for a while and Agent K took the child with him.

I wonder if that child was actually Agent J in the future or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the kid was Agent J.  Earlier in the movie it's alluded that J grew up without a father figure, but couldn't remember what happened to him, he just disappeared.  We later find out that J's father was killed by Boris.  In an act of sympathy K wiped the kid's memory, giving us the reason for why J couldn't remember his father.

Answer (score 3):

the little boy's name was James, the same name as agent J. It seems that the implication is that this military man was, indeed, J's father and raising the boy became a responsibility of K.

Comment: I'm doubt that K actually raised the boy/J. If that was true, they surely would've recognised each other when they met later during the plot of MIB 1. Also the MIB don't have family.

Comment: "raising" is a bit of an overstatement, but certainly "looking out for." though it doesn't fully scan with the relationship in the first movie, in this one, he clearly knows the secret and is trying to protect J from finding out.

Comment: I agree with Dan, maybe "Monitoring", is a better word than raising. When J's father died is also when K stopped smiling.